# WP Query search parameter

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some problem with search results. I'm trying to find a term with title like "A.1."

My query id:

[image]

As you see I'm making some sanitization here but the problem is:

1. I'm writing "A 1" in search bar -> it's ok
2. I'm writing "A.1" in search bar -> it's ok
3. I'm writing "A.1." in search bar -> it's ok
4. BUT when I'm writing "A1" in search bar -> it's NOT ok

It's a big problem for me. How can I change it?

Comment: `A 1` probably gets taken apart at the space, and causes a condition such as `WHERE title LIKE '%A%' OR title LIKE '%1%'` - which obviously won't work with `A1`. So you would have to find some sort of pattern that allows you to detect this "type" of search term, and then split it and _make_ it into `A 1` yourself.

Comment: Unless otherwise specified, WordPress will take care of escaping things properly when using core functions such as `get_terms`. The function `sanitize_title_for_query` should be removed because the default implementation by core is the slug function which, among other things, replaces spaces with dashes.

Comment: @ChrisHaas it's make sense but when I'm deleting a sanitize function- the first point doesn't working. So maybe get_terms() is not sanitizing the search field in this way?

Comment: I can't help you directly, but I can tell you that whatever you pass in `search` will be wrapped in `%`. So if you pass `A. 1` then `LIKE %A. 1%` will be used. Also, the search will be done against both the name and the slug. The sanitization that you are currently using probably only matches the slug right now. I'm not really certain of a clean way to match `A1` against `A. 1`, unfortunately